# <strong></strong> or <b> are getting displayed as string

Tags: lightning-web-components, js

I have a custom label in salesforce where I have given 'This will delete the file FILENAME'
In js I'm replacing FILENAME with actual file name

```
var updatedlabel = this.label.DeleteFileConfirmation.replace("FILENAME", fileName);
```

I tried using `<strong>` and `<b>` with filename. But  or  are getting displayed as a string along with filename instead of making it bold. Even `<b>${fileName}</b>` didn't work Anybody has any idea?
js:

```
   handleRowAction(event) {
        let actionName = event.detail.action.name; 
        let record_name = event.detail.row.name;

        switch (actionName) {
            case 'Preview':  
               //do something            
                break;

            case 'Download':     
                //do something   
                break;
            
            case 'Remove':
                this.removeFile(record_name);
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

    removeFile(fileName) {
            var updatedlabel = this.label.DeleteConfirmation.replace("FILENAME","<strong>"+ fileName+"</strong>");
            this.message = updatedlabel.split("<br/><br/>")[0];
            this.newLineMessage = updatedlabel.split("<br/><br/>")[1];
            this.showConfirmDialog = true;
    }
```

I cant make this bold in html as its taken from custom label
custom label

```
   <labels>
        <fullName>DeleteConfirmation</fullName>
        <categories>Message</categories>
        <language>en_US</language>
        <protected>true</protected>
        <shortDescription>DeleteConfirmation</shortDescription>
        <value>This will delete the file FILENAME.</value>
    </labels>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use `lightning-formatted-text` in the HTML template in order to display that. Whats there at HTML side?

Comment: html:  <c-apo-modal title={label.Confirmation} title-alignment="left" open={showConfirmDialog} onclose={handleConfirmDialogNo}
        onconfirm={handleConfirmDialogYes} variant="success" region-right-left-button={label.No}
        region-right-right-button={label.Yes}>
        <div class="slds-m-left--large slds-m-bottom--x-large">{message}</div>
        <div class="slds-m-left--large slds-m-bottom--medium">{newLineMessage}</div>
    </c-apo-modal>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lightning-formatted-rich-text` to display the `newLineMessage`.

```
<lightning-formatted-rich-text value={newLineMessage}>
</lightning-formatted-rich-text>
```

It supports strong and many other HTML tags. you can check them all here [Supported HTML Tags and attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-rich-text/documentation)

Comment: That worked! Thanks